# Foundation Clearing Configuration: Sizing Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

In the Foundation docs [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html), there are configuration options under "SCSS" - how exactly do I configure my height? Does this go in a script tag on the HTML page? I've been making custom changes to CSS in a custom.css file.

Comment: have you checked [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html)? I have only used it with text but it may work

Comment: height is variable with you dont set height on columns